# How to change Clojure or Lein's Clojure default version?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm not sure why but when I enter the REPL through `$ clojure` or `$ lein repl`, `>(clojure-version)` says '1.2.1'. I want it to say '1.5'.

Version 1.5 works fine in my projects managed by lein. I just want to tell lein to always use 1.5 by default, instead of 1.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently this isn't supported outside a project, but it's being worked on: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/966

A workaround for now is just to specify it in your project.clj

Further recommendation: upgrade to Leiningen 2.0.

Comment: When creating new projects, how to tell lein to use 1.5 instead of 1.4? (I mean by default, so I don't have to edit project.clj every single time). Adding 1.5 as a dependency in profiles.clj didn't work.

Comment: I asked technomancy on IRC just now. He said: "REPL's outside projects are hard coded to lein's version of clojure".

Comment: BTW, https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/966 is not the underlying issue (according, again, to an IRC discussion) "You can use :dependencies (in `/.lein/profiles.clj`) to add things to the non-project REPL" but "you just can't use `profiles.clj` to replace things that have already been loaded"